# django dynamic form creation

Tags: django, forms

Django and programming newbie with a question about how to build a dynamic form. How do I create a form that allows the user to edit all instances of an object from a single form instead of just one instance at a time on the form?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at Django's formsets: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/forms/formsets/